# Command argument string is empty in rowcommand event c#

Tags: c#, gridview, commandargument

I have a gridview. Inside it I have a link button.  I want to get the row index of the button which was clicked inside the rowcommand event handler. This can be done using the command argument property. however it is returning empty string and there by getting an exception.

This is the line present inside event handler

```
Int indexval = Convert.ToInt32(e.commandArgument.ToString());
```

I've also tried this to get row index.
Inside aspx page:

```
commandArgument= <%#container.DataItem%>
```

But this also returns empty string
 Tried like this in rowcommand event

```
Gridview gr = (gridview)sender;
Int Ind = gr.rows.selectedIndex.
```

Here Ind value shows as -1

There are some questions on this but all are in VB.net
I want the solution to this to be in c#.

PS I'm new to c# and asp.net

Answer (score 0):

I use `CommandField`

Add this CommandField to your GridView `<Columns>...</Columns>`

```
<asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="true" SelectText="View/Edit" ItemStyle-Width="60" />
```

This ties in to `GridView_SelectedIndexChanging` which gives you the RowIndex:

```
protected void gvCategories_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
    int rowIndex = e.NewSelectedIndex;
}
```